# How to do Bash process substitution in Scala?

Tags: scala

How would something like `diff <(echo aoeu) <(echo snth)` be done in Scala?

I've tried using [the sys.process interface](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/sys/process/package.html) as follows:

```
"diff <(echo aoeu) <(echo snth)".!
```

...however, this doesn't interpret the `<()` as subprocess substitution.

Comment: `"foo".!` uses `/bin/sh`, not bash, as the shell interpreting `foo` as a script. Even if your `/bin/sh` is provided by bash, it runs in POSIX compatibility mode when invoked in this manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import scala.sys.process._

def diff(one: String, two: String):
  String = Seq(
    "bash", "-c", """
       diff <(printf '%s\n' "$1") \
            <(printf '%s\n' "$2"); retval=$?
       (( retval == 1 )) || exit "$retval"
    """, "_", one, two).!!
```

This can be tested in practice:

```
scala> diff("hello", "world")
res1: String =
"1c1
< hello
---
> world
"
```

---

To break down the reasoning:

- Invoking a sequence, rather than a string, allows data (in my examples `hello` and `world`; in yours, `aoeu` and `snth`) to be passed out-of-band from code. This is critical to avoiding [injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) when such content is parameterized.
- Invoking `bash` as your executable ensures that [process substitution](http://wooledge.org/mywiki/ProcessSubstitution) syntax is available.
- Checking for the exit status of 1 (and coercing it to 0) avoids scala treating a case where `diff` returns an exit status indicating that the two inputs are not identical as an error, while ensuring that other errors still become exceptions in scala.
- Using `printf '%s\n' "$1"` instead of `echo "$1"` avoids ambiguities in [the POSIX definition of `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html) (see in particular the APPLICATION USAGE section).
- Passing an explicit argument of `_` fills in the `argv[0]` slot, (aka `$0`).

---

Note that invoking a sequence rather than a string also prevents you from needing a shell *at all* in many cases: `Seq("hello", "world").!` doesn't need to invoke any shell, but can be implemented so as to directly starts an executable named `hello`, whereas `"hello world".!` is equivalent to `Seq("sh", "-c", "hello world").!`, with an extra executable invocation with both performance cost and potential security vulnerabilities required for implementation. See [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)) for an example of a (now-near-universally-patched) case where a shell invocation with no explicit user-controlled parameters could still be vulnerable in practice (when invoked from a web server following CGI conventions for exporting request parameters as environment variables); avoiding unnecessary shells is thus preferable behavior where feasible.